# Gnuplot: Plotting multiple series on graph, but number of different series to overlay unknown ahead of time

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to write a script wrapping gnuplot that will take a dataset and produce an overlayed graph, the number of series to be plotted based on the number of distinct values in a given column, or based on the number of different datasets in the file.  An example file would be:

```
#SeriesName x y
Series1 0 10
Series1 1 11
Series1 2 13
...
SeriesN 0 14
SeriesN 1 19
SeriesN 2 15
```

I have this in one continuous set of lines, but I can split it into index-able chunks if necessary.  The problem is that I don't know the different names of the SeriesName values I'll have ahead of time, nor how many of distinct values there will be.  But I want one line on the graph per distinct value of SeriesName.  I can see how to make graphs if I know ahead of time the different values of SeriesName, but I don't know how to tell gnuplot to "make one line per value of series, and label each line with the name that is the value of SeriesName that was used for each line."

Can gnuplot do this?  Otherwise, I can make two passes through the data, the first one of which I will gather the unique values of SeriesName, and then use bash/perl/python to explicitly build a `plot' statement, but it seems like gnuplot should have some functionality for a user to have to avoid that.  Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I also posted to a forum to where the author of *Gnuplot in Action* (Philipp Janert) posts, and I posted a workaround to my own problem, but I don't think it qualifies as an answer, as what it ultimately does is make a second run through the data and then does a source code filter on gnuplot commands to make a gnuplot script compliant with a particular dataset.  I would think that there would be an answer using just the syntax of gnuplot better than what I did.  For reference, here is the link: http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=122752#122752

Comment: sadly the link is dead ...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, here is a solution which works with gnuplot>=4.4.0 and gnuplot 5.x.
When the series label changes in column 1 it will be added to a string. This string will be used later to plot the legend.

**Data:** `SO8812078.dat`

```
#SeriesName x y
Series1 0 10
Series1 1 11
Series1 2 13

Series2 0 12
Series2 1 13
Series2 2 14

SeriesN 0 14
SeriesN 1 19
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### take legend from column
reset

FILE = "SO8812078.dat"

myTitles = ''
set key noautotitle

plot t1='' FILE u (t0=t1,t1=strcol(1),t0 ne t1?myTitles=myTitles.' '.t1:0,$2):3:(words(myTitles)) w lp pt 7 lc var, \
     for [i=0:words(myTitles)] 1/0 w lp pt 7 lc i ti word(myTitles,i)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.4.0)

[image]